Change the the java used in bootBuildImage from bellsoft to corretto when build image using bootBuildImage
I want to change the Java used with Spring boot bootBuildImage from Bellsoft to Amazon Corretto
I am using Java 21 and Spring Boot 3.3.5
Edit:
I don't want to change the java used by Gradle, I want to change the java used by bootBuildImage builder

The Spring Boot Gradle plugin's bootBuildImage goal uses Paketo Cloud Native Buildpacks builder by default. Paketo documents how to configure the builder to use a different JVM than the default Bellsoft Liberica by specifying the buildpacks to use.
Spring Boot has an example of configuring buildpacks similar to the pack example in the Paketo documentation.
Putting those two pieces of documentation together, you'd do something like this in your build.gradle file:
tasks.named("bootBuildImage") {
    buildpacks = ["gcr.io/paketo-buildpacks/amazon-corretto", "urn:cnb:builder:paketo-buildpacks/java"]
}


thanks a lot. It works as expected something I also noticed it's possible to add buildpacks directly to bootBuildImage something like this
bootBuildImage {
buildpacks = ["gcr.io/paketo-buildpacks/amazon-corretto", "urn:cnb:builder:paketo-buildpacks/java"]
}

Generally speaking, tasks.named("bootBuildImage") {} and just bootBuildImage {} to configure a task will behave similarly. The difference is how early Gradle does the configuration. There is some information about this in the Gradle documentation: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/task_configuration_avoidance.html.
